# Is there a way to bind a variable to a request in tower-http / hyper / axum?

Tags: rust, hyper, rust-axum, rust-tower

I'm trying to add a request id to each tracing event. I can do it with [`tower_http::trace`](https://docs.rs/tower-http/0.1.1/tower_http/trace/) like this:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct RequestSpan;

impl<B> tower_http::trace::MakeSpan<B> for RequestSpan {
    fn make_span(&mut self, request: &http::Request<B>) -> tracing::Span {
        tracing::error_span!(
            "rq",
            id = %ulid::Ulid::new().to_string(),
            method = %request.method(),
            uri = %request.uri(),
            version = ?request.version(),
        )
    }
}

...

let middleware_stack = tower::ServiceBuilder::new()
    .layer(TraceLayer::new_for_http().make_span_with(RequestSpan))
```

It works in the scope of the server, but I also need to pass the request id into an external task queue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Custom data can be stored on requests via [`Extensions`](https://docs.rs/http/latest/http/struct.Extensions.html). They are accessible via `.extensions()` and `.extensions_mut()` on a [`http::request::Request`](https://docs.rs/http/latest/http/request/struct.Request.html) (which works for [hyper](https://crates.io/crates/hyper) and [tower-http](https://crates.io/crates/tower-http)) or via the same methods on [`axum::response::RequestParts`](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/extract/struct.RequestParts.html) (which works for [axum](https://crates.io/crates/axum)).

Extensions are primarily used to move data between services/middleware to the route handler and vice-versa. The collection acts like a map with values keyed-off of their type, so if you want to store a `Ulid` you probably want to wrap it in some more descriptive type like `RequestId(Ulid)` just to ensure it doesn't conflict with other uses.

See also:

- [What is the role of a "Extension" in actix-web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68992781/what-is-the-role-of-a-extension-in-actix-web)
- [What are Rust's HTTP extensions?](https://blog.adamchalmers.com/what-are-extensions/) (blog)

Answer (score -1):

I've made it into a [little crate](https://github.com/imbolc/tower-request-id) following a solution from [rustlang forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-axum-hyper-request-local-variables/65205/3)

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question: "Is there a way to bind a variable to Axum request?", and what answer there could be is obscured behind a link. It is nice that you were able to find the solution to your problem and were even able to contribute back to the community. But a user looking how to use "request local variables" in hyper/axum/tower will have trouble applying this answer to their use-case.